# Skip Gradle task in local environment

Tags: gradle

Is there a way to configure a custom Gradle task such that it only runs in non-local environments?

```
task runMeOnlyInNonLocalEnvironments {    
  doLast {
    println "This is not a local environment"    
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a local environment? Do you mean that you want things to happen differently on ie CI? You could try setting some build environment settings, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `task.onlyIf` to tell Gradle when to skip it. You will still need a way to figure out when a machine is "non-local". If you have control over those machines, the easiest way is probably to create an environment property on them that marks them as a particular type. For instance, if you want to run the task on CI machines only, it could look like:

```
task runMeOnlyInNonLocalEnvironments  {
    onlyIf {
        System.getenv().containsKey('CI')
    }

    doLast {
        println "This is not a local environment"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
tasks.register("runMeOnlyInNonLocalEnvironments") {
    doLast {
      if(project.hasProperty("isNonLocal")) {
         println("Running task in non local environment")
      }
    }
}
```

Then you have to set the project property, that can be achieved through following methods:

1. gradle.properties

   Put any one of the following in gradle.properties file

   a) `isNonLocal=true`

   b) `systemProp.org.gradle.project.isNonLocal=true`

   Then run `gradle runMeOnlyInNonLocalEnvironments`
2. Command line argument

   `gradle -PisNonLocal=true runMeOnlyInNonLocalEnvironments`
3. Through environment variable

   In unix variants you can type in the command prompt where you are running gradle, `export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_isNonLocal=true`

   Then run `gradle runMeOnlyInNonLocalEnvironments`